# GDAL virtual file system (VSI) file system requiring credentials in QField

Tags: qfield, qfield-cloud

I'm trying to connect to a private AWS S3 bucket containing Cloud-Optimized GeoTIFFs (COGs).

I've tried setting AWS access keys globally (by manually writing the keys in global variables on the phone), adding an xml files, configuring QField Cloud environment variables, and adding a "credential" file in the Android folder—all unsuccessful.

In QField on windows, I see the layers without any issue (the credential are stored in my environment variables).

I can load the layer with /vsicurl/ with a signed url, but since it is time limited so it's not a valid option.

I haven't tried other cloud provider (gcloud, azure) but I assume it's the same issue.

In Qfield I receive this error message:

[image]

Phone: Google Pixel 6a

QField version: 3.1.3 Borneo (14a225 v3.1.3)